# Custom Callout gesture recognition

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer, mkannotationview

I have custom view after select `MKAnnotationView` and with that i try to add a gesture recognizer like this:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)selectedAnnotationView {
    if([selectedAnnotationView.annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomPinAnnotation class]]) {
        CustomPinAnnotation *annotation = selectedAnnotationView.annotation;
        [selectedAnnotationView setCalloutOffset:CGPointMake(0,selectedAnnotationView.frame.size.height)];

        CalloutView *calloutView = [[CalloutView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, selectedAnnotationView.frame.size.width, selectedAnnotationView.frame.size.height*2)];

    [selectedAnnotationView addSubview:calloutView];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:annotationAnimationTime animations:^{
        [calloutView setFrame:CGRectMake(-expandingAnnotationWidth/8, 0, [calloutView calculateWurstLenghtFromText:selectedAnnotationView.annotation.title], selectedAnnotationView.frame.size.height*2)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(calloutTapped:)];
        [calloutView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
        [calloutView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }];
}
```

In the screen below you can see how it looks like expanded and not:
[image]

The problem is that the gesture recognizer works only on marked area and not on entire callout:

[image]

I probably know what's happen - i add subview to `MKAnnotation` which is to small. But how to fix this? There is another way to draw callout or maybe i can expand tappable area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your annotation's frame is probably too small. Even if you set the callout to be big enough, its parent, the annotation, itself is small. Had the same problem and it's really messy to solve it.

If you don't want to mess with frames and selected states and also because you already are using a custom view which is added, why don't you do the following :

- add the custom callout view as a completely new/different annotation/overlay when an annotation is selected ( not as a subview like now )
- remove it when your annotation is deselected

You only need to position it correctly and won't even need a gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 1):

1Maybe you could try to change this:

```
CalloutView *calloutView = [[CalloutView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, selectedAnnotationView.frame.size.width, selectedAnnotationView.frame.size.height*2)];
```

To this:

```
 CalloutView *calloutView = [[CalloutView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)];
```

And see if it works, because I have a feeling that annotationView.frame is too small and sets your calloutView just to this small area. If it's hardcoded it might work.

Comment: But the frame is right - i see that drawing correctly. Besides this frame is changed with animation couple lines below mentioned one.

Comment: Just log your calloutView.frame and check its values. I might be wrong, but I had a similar issue before and this was causing it. I will take a look into may code and see how I managed to handle this tapGesture

Comment: I logged it : `frame = (-25 0; 270 120);` after animation. Is right size.

Comment: I had problems with registering taps to a button, so I had to subclass MKAnnotationView and change few things arround like
`-(void)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
return YES;
}
-(UIView*)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
 if(hitView)
 {
   return hitView;
 }

 for(UIView *subView in self.subviews)
 {
  CGPoint inPoint = [self convertPoint:point fromView:subView];
  hitView = [subView hitTest:inPoint withEvent:event];
  if(hitView)
  {
    return hitView;
  }
 }
 return nil;
}`